# Generating all the increasing digit numbers

Tags: c#, java

I came across the following question for an interview.

For a given number of digits, generate all the numbers such that the value of a higher order digit is less than a lower order digit.

145 // 1 < 4 < 5

Is there a better (efficient) way to do this than the one I have come up with:

```
public static void GenerateSpecialNumbers(int noDigits)
{           
    int prod = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < noDigits; i++)
    {
        prod = prod * 10;
    }
    int minValue = prod/10;
    int maxValue = prod - 1;        

    for(int i = minValue; i < maxValue; i++)
    {
        bool isValid = true;

        int num  = i;
        int max = int.MaxValue;

        while(num > 0)
        {
            int digit = num % 10;
            if(digit >= max)
            {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
            max = digit;            

            num = num/10;
        }

        if(isValid)
            Console.WriteLine(i);               
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Output for 3 digits:

123
124
125
126
127
128
129
134
135
136
137
138
139
145
146
147
148
149
156
157
158
159
167
168
169
178
179
189
234
235
236
237
238
239
245
246
247
248
249
256
257
258
259
267
268
269
278
279
289
345
346
347
348
349
356
357
358
359
367
368
369
378
379
389
456
457
458
459
467
468
469
478
479
489
567
568
569
578
579
589
678
679
689
789

Comment: digits always increase from left to right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice puzzle!  Here's my take:

```
static void Main()
{
    WriteNumbers(3);
}

static void WriteNumbers(int digits, int number = 0)
{
    int i = (number % 10) + 1;
    number *= 10;
    for (; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        if (digits == 1)
            Console.WriteLine(number + i);
        else
            WriteNumbers(digits - 1, number + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop condition can be reduced to `i <= (10 - digits)`, but otherwise that's it.  Although, I'd just pass the previous digit as a parameter instead of using an expensive modulo operation to calculate it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this problem has a simple recursive description that constructs all the numbers without having to test and throw any away.

For example, the valid `n` digit numbers include "1".append(all valid `n-1` digit numbers using only digits `>1`)

Each digit has a lower bound of one plus the digit immediately to its left.  Can you find a simple upper bound?

Comment: I think I did not convey the question well. Could you please check the desired output.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more.

Comment: @mkg, I posted my answer summarized this (I hope). http://stackoverflow.com/a/9208784/352101

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i1 from 1 to 9)
for (i2 from 1 to i1 - 1)
for (i3 from 1 to i2 - 1)
 print(i1 * 1 + i2 * 10 + i3 * 100);
```

No recursion needed for fixed-length numbers. Easy to code and fail-safe.

Please note that the loop upper bounds are not fixed. This is what makes this work.

Comment: What's the deal with 0 and decreasing instead of increasing?

Comment: "0" was a bug. I changed it to one. i1 is the *last* digit, not the first one. The last one is the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

Since I like table-based things, I would generate the table for n = 2 first (< 100 entries, obviously) and just hold it in an initialized array.

Then f(n) = the digits in the sequence N [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] composed with f(n-1) where f(n-1)[0] > N

```
i.e. for n = 3:
1, f(2) where f(2)[0] > 1: 123, 124, 125, ...
2, f(2) where f(2)[0] > 2: 234, 235, 236, ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with help from [@Hand-E-Food](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202777/352101) and @Ben Voigt's comment. I feel this is easier to understand:

```
        static void WriteNumbers(int digits, int left=0,int number=0)
        {
           for(int i=left+1; i<10; i++)
           {
               if(digits==1)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(number*10+i);
               }
               else
               {
                   WriteNumbers(digits - 1, i, number*10 + i);
               }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: if there are N possible digit values, and you want to pick M of them, the number of possibilities is "N choose M".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution (albeit kind of hack-ish) that will work for any number of digits:

```
private static void printSpecialNumbers(int noOfDigits){
    int max = (int) Math.pow(10, noOfDigits);
    int min = (int) Math.pow(10, noOfDigits-1);

    for(int i = min; i < max; i++){
        if(isSpecialNumber(i))
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}

private static boolean isSpecialNumber(int i){

    String intString = String.valueOf(i);
    String[] digits = intString.split("");

    for(int k = 1; k < digits.length-1; k++){
        if(Integer.valueOf(digits[k]) >= Integer.valueOf(digits[k+1]))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```